# Is there is a relation between temperature of engine and the torque

Tags: motorcycle, suzuki, torque, gsxr

In my previous place, I used to start my Gsxr-750 and get a flat street. Without waiting the engine get hot. It used to work very well.

Recently I move to a new apartment. In this new apartment when I left my place, I get a big hill. I feel my motorbike losing torque during the uphill. This happens with the 1st gear.

Sometimes the bike "chokes" (I'm not sure if this is the correct word in English) but doesn't stop, but definitely, my bike kicks the torque.

Another day I wait at the moment the engine gets more than 50-celsius I had the feeling that my bike not "chokes" as it chokes when I get out with a cold engine.

About the bike is a Gsxr-750 13 with 8000km. I did all the services with Authorized Suzuki.

Answer (score 2):

From your description I would say that the sputtering under heavy loads and high temperatures is due to insufficient fuel delivery.

Common suspects that cause this condition on fuel injected setups include:

- a clogged fuel filter
- a weak fuel pump
- low fuel rail pressure

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course there is relation between :

- Temperature
- Engine component material
- Type of Fuel System
- Type of Oil Lubricants

Oil :
Every engine with lubrication system inside, needs to be idled until the oil covers all the engine components. If not engine components may get hard friction without getting the oil lubricates. e.g Piston Ring, and it can make your bike hard to get some torque because of the friction.

Temperature :
When the engine is cold, the material shrinks, so there is some changes at the compression ratio, and that makes the power slightly different, or maybe the engine cannot starts.

Fuel Systems :
Engine with carburetors needs to be waited until get some heat, because in the carburetor system, all the system are mechanical. So everything depends on the component conditions. But with the Fuel Injection system, some components are Computerized, so there are less interaction with outside conditions, e.g temperature.